# multilanguage support

Tags: android

how can i create an application which support korean as well as english language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [android developers localization guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: Also, here is an example of using localization if you needed a look at one, http://www.droidnova.com/make-use-of-simple-multilanguage-support,85.html